# How to get the actual exception out of the facebook sdk (3 beta) on android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am currently having the following problem: I am developping an android application which shares content via the Facebook API (API 3.x beta). However, after I successfully log in, I cannot get any information from the profile, nor post information to the profile even though my permissions are configured correctly.
I continuesly get the following exception in my logcat:

```
 D/com.facebook.RequestAsyncTask(25792): onPostExecute: exception encountered during request:
```

However, I do not get the actual exception. My question therefore is: how can I get the actual exception to be reported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigh.. I found the problem:
in com.facebook.ReqeustAsyncTask , change line 152 into:

```
 Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: exception encountered during request: ".concat(exception.getMessage()));
```

and then you will get the actual exception reported...
Alteratively you can also add %s to the String.format call as Ming Li points out.

Comment: yup, that looks like a bug. You should also be able to just add %s in the String.format call rather than changing the whole line.